# Four dice are thrown simultaneously . The probablity that 4 and 3 appear on two of the die given that 5 and 6 have appeared on other two.

Tags: probability

Four dice are thrown simultaneously . The probablity that $4$ and $3$ appear on two of the die given that 5 and 6 have appeared on other two.

In the above question the favorable cases will be $4!$ $(4,3,5,6)$  can  appear on dice but I cannot understand the sample space of this question . According to me it should be $(6⋅6)$ but it is incorrect ..... Please explain

Comment: You should use conditional probabilities... But... _what is your question exactly_...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N:=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^4$ and $N_i:=\{\langle a,b,c,d\rangle\in N\mid i\notin\{a,b,c,d\}\}$ for $i\in N$.

As sample space we can use the set $N_5^c\cap N_6^c$ so to be found as denominator is: $$|N_5^c\cap N_6^c|=|N|-|N_5\cup N_6|=|N|-|N_5|-|N_6|+|N_5\cap N_6|=6^4-5^4-5^4+4^4=302$$

As you allready noted there are $4!$ favorable cases, so the probability that you are looking for is: $$\frac{4!}{302}=\frac{12}{151}$$

Comment: What's wrong with using ${4\choose2}*2*1*6*6$ as the sample space? (all possible combinations including at least one 5 and one 6)

Comment: The space proposed in my answer is exactly the collection of all combinations that contain at least one 5 and one 6. I do not understand the number you mention. It is definitely not its cardinality.

Comment: 6^4 represents all possible combinations. If we want to count only those which include (at least) one 5/6 then: select 2 die which will serve as the 5/6 (4choose2) * select 5 or 6 for the first slot (2) * select the remaining number for the second slot (1) * any number for the 3rd slot (6) * any number for the 4th slot (6)

Comment: Then e.g. combination 5656 will be counted more than once.

Comment: right. i knew i was missing something. thank you!